# How to spin a 2D quad in place using only matrices?

Tags: opengl, mathematics, rotation, matrix

In short, I have a textured 2D quad (a sprite).  I would like to rotate/spin it about the z-axis (coming out of the screen) using nothing but matrices.

If I do the following to a transform with scale in it already, the object spins, but also follows a circular path around the origin.   As a test, if I first undo the scale, then this works fine (the object spins in place).  But I'm not normally keeping scale, orientation and translation separate and then computing the matrix every frame in this case.  I'm mutating the matrix all the time.  So this isn't workable.  Can this be done without first undoing the scale?

- `self` is the current transformation matrix (4x4)
- `pivot` is the "center" of the quad's AABB (recomputed immediately before this)
- eulerAngles is a vec3 containing {0.0, 0.0, z-angle}

  ```
  /* translate to the origin */
  translate(self, -pivot);

  /* rotate */
  rotate(self, eulerAngles);

  /* go back */
  translate(self, pivot);
  ```

(I'm using OpenGL, but that probably doesn't matter much here)

There are other related articles, but I didn't get to a solution.  I'm linking for reference:

- [Combining rotation,scaling around a pivot with translation into a matrix](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61473/combining-rotation-scaling-around-a-pivot-with-translation-into-a-matrix)
- [How can I rotate about an arbitrary point in 3D (instead of the origin)?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19297/how-can-i-rotate-about-an-arbitrary-point-in-3d-instead-of-the-origin)

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve that. What is the reason why you would like to _not_ store separate data for scale, rotation and translation, and recompute the transformation matrix every frame?

Comment: Is keeping everything in SQT format the best way to do Transformation matrices? (S: Scale, Q: Quaternion for Orientation, and T: Translation)

Comment: Yes, it is. You have finer control on the order of operations, and you reduce the errors that would accumulate over time due to floating point calculations.

Comment: Normally you would call `scale()` after an object was moved to the origin. (It means, between your `translate()` calls.) Why do you use `scale()` as a first transformation?