# Setting relative anchor point via matrix

Tags: opengl, mathematics, matrix, webgl

The page at https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html provides an example for rotating around the center of the image:

`// make a matrix that will move the origin of the 'F' to its center.
var moveOriginMatrix = m3.translation(-50, -75);`

Similarly, the library I'm using (gl-matrix), provides an ability to rotate around an `origin vector`:

> fromRotationTranslationScaleOrigin [...] Creates a matrix from a quaternion rotation, vector translation and vector scale, rotating and scaling around the given origin

However, I'd like to generically set a rotation vector based on the relative local transform - e.g. something like giving [0.5,0.5, 0] as the `origin` parameter to `fromRotationTranslationScaleOrigin()` and have it always rotate around the center.

Would this require handling it somewhere else in the pipeline? (e.g. after composing with the perspective matrix) - or are there some best-practices ways of handling this?

I'd *also* like a matrix to allow centering within another's `world` matrix but that's a different question I guess :)

Comment: You have to have the object store its translation vector (the pivot). This way when you rotate, you subtract the pivot vector, rotate, then add the pivot vector back. see the answers at  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19297/how-can-i-rotate-about-an-arbitrary-point-in-3d-instead-of-the-origin?rq=1, https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61473/combining-rotation-scaling-around-a-pivot-with-translation-into-a-matrix.