# Rotating a circle on its axis

Tags: opengl, 3d, rotation

I have a circular shape object, which I want to rotate like a fan along it's own axis.

I can change the rotation in any direction i.e. `dx`, `dy`, `dz` using my transformation matrix.

The following it's the code:

```
 Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();
 matrix.setIdentity();
 Matrix4f.translate(translation, matrix, matrix);
 Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rx), new Vector3f(1,0,0), matrix, matrix);
 Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(ry), new Vector3f(0,1,0), matrix, matrix);
 Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rz), new Vector3f(0,0,1), matrix, matrix);
 Matrix4f.scale(new Vector3f(scale,scale,scale), matrix, matrix);
```

My vertex code:

```
 vec4 worldPosition = transformationMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
 vec4 positionRelativeToCam = viewMatrix*worldPosition;
 gl_Position = projectionMatrix *positionRelativeToCam;
```

But, it's not rotating along its own axis, it is flipping like a coin instead. What am I missing here?

Comment: The above one is for Y rotation , while moving along Z axis it's rotating fine but it's Y position changes

Comment: If you want it to rotate around its own axis, then how about doing a rotation around its own axis, instead of 3 rotations around the X/Y/Z axes?

Answer (score 2):

You apply your transformations in the wrong order. The usual way is scale first, then rotate, and lastly translate. Currently you are translating first, then rotating, and finally scaling.

See [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16719/what-is-the-correct-order-to-multiply-scale-rotation-and-translation-matrices-f) for more information.

Comment: When I am using Z rotation it's rotating and revolving both i.e Y position is also changing so what element in my matrix should i change

Comment: Have you checked this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions

Comment: Here is my full code can't figure out it yet https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1glu6x4ajd6y4mw/AABvIPdCcUw4HwI9aZkiM5z4a/src?dl=0 any idea ?

Comment: Did you even read my answer? You haven't done anything to your code. Anyways there's no way I'll have time nor interest to dig through all of your code.

Comment: I applied the tranformation as suggest you but still no luck

Comment: it same rotating and revolving