# Rotating an Object Around an Axis

Tags: opengl, graphics, matrix, transformation

I have a circular shape object, which I want to rotate like a fan along it's own axis.

I can change the rotation in any direction i.e. dx, dy, dz using my transformation matrix.

The following it's the code:

```
 Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();
 matrix.setIdentity();
 Matrix4f.translate(translation, matrix, matrix);
 Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rx), new Vector3f(1,0,0), matrix, matrix);
 Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(ry), new Vector3f(0,1,0), matrix, matrix);
 Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rz), new Vector3f(0,0,1), matrix, matrix);
 Matrix4f.scale(new Vector3f(scale,scale,scale), matrix, matrix);
```

My vertex code:

```
 vec4 worldPosition = transformationMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
 vec4 positionRelativeToCam = viewMatrix*worldPosition;
 gl_Position = projectionMatrix *positionRelativeToCam;
```

Main Game Loop:

```
  Object.increaseRotation(dxf,dyf,dzf);
```

But, it's not rotating along it's own axis. What am I missing here? I want something like this. Please Help

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotating a circle on its axis](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130814/rotating-a-circle-on-its-axis)

Comment: You can edit your questions instead of creating a new one just to add a gif :)

Comment: I can't tell if there is anything wrong. But why don't you try putting all of the matrix calculations in one line, that's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: @JasonPh here full code https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1glu6x4ajd6y4mw/AABvIPdCcUw4HwI9aZkiM5z4a/src?dl=0 any idea..